# Uploading a baked Wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ftp

Is there a way to upload a baked Wordress site from a fully functional server with PHP and MySQL database to a bare FTP server without PHP and MySQL?
In the baked version the CMS is not needed. Justa site to work with static HTML and CSS files to present a functional snapshot of a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the plugin duplicator which is quite good

Comment: it worked sort of..
after installing the site I get an error:
Your server is running PHP version 5.3.28-0+tld2 but WordPress 5.4.2 requires at least 5.6.20.

Is there a way to do a baked version?

Comment: Can you modify the php version of your server?

Comment: I didn't find any answer to my question but managed to upgrade PHP and just upload a fully functional site on the server.